ORA-13199: Error during RDF Network creation. EXECUTE SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK fails on Oracle 23ai
I ran Oracle 23ai using VirtualBox appliance and followed Oracle's guide "2.1 Getting Started with Semantic Data in a Schema-Private Network" from https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/rdfrm/getting-started-rdf-data-schema-private-network.html .
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password: oracle

Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.4.0.24.05

SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE rdf_tblspace
 DATAFILE 'rdf_tblspace.dat' SIZE 1024M REUSE
 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 256M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
 SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;

Tablespace created.

SQL> CREATE USER rdfuser IDENTIFIED BY Password99 QUOTA 5G ON rdf_tblspace;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW TO rdfuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> CONNECT rdfuser/Password99

Connected.

SQL> EXECUTE SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK('rdf_tblspace', network_owner=>'rdfuser', network_name=>'rdfnetwork');
BEGIN SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK('rdf_tblspace', network_owner=>'rdfuser', network_name=>'rdfnetwork'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-13199: Error during RDF Network creation: step_num=2.2
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "SYS.SDO_RDF_SYS" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.SDO_RDF_SYS"
RDF_EBTRC [
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_INTERNAL", line 32175
]
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_INTERNAL", line 33028
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_INTERNAL", line 33002
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_INTERNAL", line 32987
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_INTERNAL", line 33024
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF", line 19006
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF", line 19040
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_APIS", line 3206
ORA-06512: at line 1
Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-13199/

ORA-13199 is an internal error. Am I missing some steps?

The relevant error code is the next line ORA-04067: not executed, package body "SYS.SDO_RDF_SYS" does not exist - the installation documentation appears to be Enabling, Downgrading, or Removing RDF Semantic Graph Support

In the latest documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/rdfrm/enabling-rdf-graph-support.html it says "RDF Semantic Graph is automatically enabled when Oracle Spatial Release 12.2 or later is installed." and also it says that you can verify by running select * from mdsys.rdf_parameter; and for me it returns what is expected:
MDSYS SEM_VERSION 23.1.0.0.0 VALID

You can run it in a fiddle

Check the solution provided in MyOracleSupport Doc ID 3030523.1 (RDF Graph Users Get ORA-4067 in Oracle Database release 23.4.0.0.0).
